# Dual Translation plane

Tags: affine-geometry

An affine plane $\mathcal{A}$ is called a translation plane if the translation group of $\mathcal{A}$ operates transitively on the point set of $\mathcal{A}$.

So how do we define the dual translation plane?

Thanks.